# System.UnauthorizedAccessException, как поймать это исключение?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, для своей программы я создал свой собственный `OpenFileDialog`, но при попытке получить список файлов в некоторых папках, с ограниченным доступом само-собой, получаю ошибку `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` и программа "вылетает". Подскажите пожалуйста как можно внутри программы эту ошибку поймать? Нужно что бы вместо "вылета" пользователь получал что-то вроде `MessageBox`.

Вот код диалогового окна:

```
public partial class dialog_open_file : Window
{
    private object null_item;
    public string selected_path;

    public dialog_open_file()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GetDrives()
    {
        foreach (string drives in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = drives;
            item.Tag = drives;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            item.Items.Add(null_item);
            item.Expanded += item_Expanded;
            item.Selected += item_Selected;
            treeview_directories.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void dialog_open_file_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetDrives();
    }

    void item_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        if (item.Items.Count == 1 && item.Items[0] == null_item)
        {
            item.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
                foreach (string folders in Directory.GetDirectories(item.Tag.ToString()))
                {
                    TreeViewItem subitem = new TreeViewItem();
                    subitem.Header = folders.Substring(folders.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    subitem.Tag = folders;
                    subitem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                    subitem.Items.Add(null_item);
                    subitem.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(item_Expanded);
                    item.Items.Add(subitem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }

    void item_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem help_item = treeview_directories.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        selected_path = help_item.Tag.ToString();
        listbox_files.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(selected_path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            ListBoxItem listitem = new ListBoxItem();
            listitem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            listitem.Tag = file;
            listbox_files.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь Visual Studio, то отладчик сообщает вам, в какой именно строчке происходит исключение. Думаю, именно этот (или охватывающий) код нужно заключить в try/catch.

Comment: @VladD, Я пробовал использовать конструкцию try/catch, но это мне не помогло. Возможно Я использовал её как-то не правильно, именно поэтому Я и обратился за помощью сюда. К сожалению отладчик не сообщает в какой именно строке возникает ошибка.

Comment: Отладчик должен сообщать о строке, в которой было выброшено исключение. Если вы видите исключение, вы в худшем случае можете просмотреть свойство `StackTrace`, там есть весь стек на момент исключения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде всего два места, которые читают список файлов или папок с диска:

первое уже обернуто в try/catch:

```
foreach (string folders in Directory.GetDirectories(item.Tag.ToString())
```

второе нужно обернуть, вместе с циклом, использующим результат:

```
// try {
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(selected_path);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    ListBoxItem listitem = new ListBoxItem();
    listitem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    listitem.Tag = file;
    listbox_files.Items.Add(listitem);
}
// } catch { MessageBox.Show(...); }
```